# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAuth') in React and GraphQL application

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, jwt, middleware

I'm encountering an error when trying to create a post in my React application using a GraphQL mutation. The error message is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAuth')",
      "status": 500
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createPost": null
  }
}
```

This suggests that the req.isAuth property is undefined when the mutation reaches my backend resolver. However, I'm sending the token in the Authorization header of my GraphQL request.

Here is how I am resolving createPost function

```
const createPost = async ({ postInput }, req) => {
  console.log(req);
  if (!req.isAuth) {
    const error = new Error("Not Authenticated");
    error.code = 401;
    throw error;
  }
  const errors = [];
  if (
    validator.isEmpty(postInput.title) ||
    !validator.isLength(postInput.title, { min: 5 })
  ) {
    errors.push("Title is invalid");
  }
  if (
    validator.isEmpty(postInput.content) ||
    !validator.isLength(postInput.content, { min: 5 })
  ) {
    errors.push("Content is invalid");
  }
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    const error = new Error("Invalid Input");
    error.data = errors;
    error.code = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  const user = await User.findById(req.userId);
  if (!user) {
    const error = new Error("Invalid User");
    error.code = 401;
    throw error;
  }
  const post = new Post({
    title: postInput.title,
    content: postInput.content,
    imageUrl: postInput.imageUrl,
    creator: user,
  });
  const createdPost = await post.save();
  user.posts.push(createdPost);
  console.log('Done Succesfully');
  return {
    ...createdPost._doc,
    _id: createdPost._id.toString(),
    createsAt: createdPost.createdAt.toISOString(),
    updatedAt: createdPost.updatedAt.toISOString(),
  };
};
```

This is my custom middleware which is used before

```
 app.use('/graphql',createHandler({
    schema: graphqlSchema,
    rootValue: graphqlResolver})
)
```

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Auth middleware executed");
  const authHeader = req.get("Authorization");
  if (!authHeader) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  console.log(authHeader);
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  let decodedToken;
  try {
    decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
  } catch (error) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  if (!decodedToken) {
    req.isAuth = false;
    return next();
  }
  req.userId = decodedToken.userId;
  req.isAuth = true;
  next();
});
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Verified the token in the Authorization header is valid and not expired.
- Ensured the middleware checking for authorization is defined and executed before the GraphQL   endpoint.
- Logged the value of req.isAuth in my backend code, but it remains undefined.
  My setup:

React application for frontend.
Express server with graphql-http and graphQL package for backend.
JWT authentication with a secret key.

This is not a professional project I am learning this online and this code is just not working for me please help.

Comment: I am new to this subject and am learning from the course on Udemy on node.js. The course is old but still covers the basics it's just the graphQL section's code is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an incorrect function signature for your mutation:

```
const createPost = async ({ postInput }, req) => {
```

Should be:

```
const createPost = async (_, { postInput }, {req}) => {
```

The first parameter is the `parent` (which should be `undefined` for a mutation), the second is the mutation variables, and the 3rd is the `context` of which `req` is a key.

Comment: I am using simple graphql-http package and graphql package for backend. After I had done the changes mentioned by you. I got different error which said that it "Cannot destructure property 'postInput' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.". To clear my code for you here is the github repository where I have stored my frontend and backed code [link](https://github.com/Sharma-Shivam2021/stackoverflow-question.git)

Comment: It appears you didn't provide the `postInput` variable to your mutation from the client.